# how create service into existing application on App Engine, without effect existing running service

Tags: google-app-engine-python

I have two running services on App Engine. One is default and another is node js service.
I want one another service deploy python service using docker.

how to do that any one have idea what are steps in term of without affecting existing services.

is that possible using UI or have to do using terminal.

Answer (score 0):

It's no different from when you created your second service

1. Create the new service (e.g create a folder for the service in your project folder, create a yaml file to handle routing for your service)
2. Update your `dispatch.yaml` file to route traffic to this new service
3. Deploy the new service

```
// assuming your new service is called 'service3' and it's in folder called `service3`
$ gcloud app deploy --project <project> service3/service3.yaml
```

4. Deploy the updated dispatch.yaml

```
// assuming the dispatch.yaml is in your root folder
$ gcloud app deploy dispatch.yaml
```

See this [article](https://nocommandline.com/blog/managing-large-apps-on-google-app-engine/) explaining/tying all the steps